# Can I use pins on USB C connector for non-USB things safely?

Tags: usb, connector, usb-device, usb-c

I'm building a product that will use HS 2.0 on USB C for data transfer and charging.  But I want to make a dumb cable that just has 3 wires connected to Ecg leads to plug into the same USB C port.  Can I keep those 3 pins on the USB socket always connected to my A2D, and simply ignore the data coming in on them if it happens to have a real USB cable connected (assumedly by looking for incoming power)?

Comment: Thunderbolt, DisplayPort, power… I don’t see why we can’t add ecg, just make sure the naming when you standardize it is confusing. (This is usb humor)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No.

Please don't use the USB connector for ECG leads, because that's unsafe.
Let's do a spot of risk analysis.  Imagine the ECG electrodes connected to a patient on one end, and to a USB plug on the other end.  Imagine all the places where somebody could accidentally stick the USB plug into: laptops, smartphones, counterfeit Chinese wall chargers.
What kind of benefit can outweigh such risk?

More generally.  Exposing common connectors (HDMI, USB, RJ-45, etc) for other purposes is usually a wrong idea.  But [the opposite] using an uncommon or proprietary connector for common communication interfaces is fine.

Comment: Thanks! It is indeed a very important issue.  Our solution was to mold the USB C connector on the ecg leads into a clunky connector that is "keyed" to only fit over our device, and will not fit into normal USB C sockets. It's useful for us to reuse the USB port for water ingress issues,and also to physically ensure that a patient can not be connected to the device and power simultaneously.  So a 2nd port that isn't USB for leads would have to be physically covering the USB C port anyway.  So we are lookiing to save money with a single USB port.  Is this possible?

Comment: If you have a USB plug, someone will find a way to plug it into a USB socket.  Furthermore, if you have the budget to do custom injection molding, you have the budget to use a proper connector.  You can use the same single-socket scheme to prevent the power cable and ECG leads from being connected simultaneously but I would check to see if that is a permissible level of protection.

Comment: On a side note, RJ-45 is not even a connector. It's an unofficial name for a wiring standard which uses a 8P8C modular jack as the connector.

Comment: and (@Justme) that connector has been used for many things over the years - I've certainly seen RS232 using it, on devices that may even predate 10base-T. (and indeed that was standardised)

Comment: How can this be unsafe? I dont think ECG leads are low impedance enough that 5V will cause a noticeable current to flow through

Comment: And besides, the USB3.0/DP alt mode pins can be used, as they also dont have a high voltage on them, arent constantly on, and no charger connects to them. I dont think this idea is that crazy

Comment: I was thinking of putting the ecg wires on 2 or 3 of the ground pins.  That way no matter what they plug the wires into, it wouldn't supply any current to the ecg wires that might be still connected to the body.  And my device could just look for a voltage on the USB cable to know if it's real USB or ecg coming in.  Sound safe?

Comment: @David "Sound safe?" - more importantly, are *you* prepared to justify your choice at an inquest? https://www.fda.gov/medical-devices/general-hospital-devices-and-supplies/medical-device-connectors

Comment: @AnasMalas Imagine that the patient end of the leads are damaged and actually penetrate the skin.  Skin is a great electrical barrier, but all the juicy liquids below the skin are great electrical *conductors*.

Comment: @AnasMalas: " Imagine all the places where somebody could accidentally stick the USB plug into: ... counterfeit Chinese wall chargers"   If that ever happens, there might just be a direct connection between patient and mains.

Comment: @OskarSkog I understand, but no counterfeit charger would ever connect to those pins. either the pins wont exist on the connector or they would be unconnected. However, the reason you give is a good reason why connecting the leads to ground wouldnt be ok. The circuit's ground may be at 230 V

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use the CC lines to negotiate entry into a newly-defined alternate mode, in a manner compliant with the specification documents. Your cable will have to complete this handshake according to the specification, so that it does not interfere with devices which do not implement your alt-mode.

Comment: There is the *Audio Adapter Accessory Mode* which requires no negotiation and is entirely passive. However, I believe that is the only fully passive "alternate mode" (note the small letters) and it is not a proper *Alternate Mode*. Indeed, AFAIK, all Alternate Modes require active negotiation. Audio Adapter Accessory Mode is its own special thing and cannot support active negotiation, since that would defeat its point.